# Show that any matrix product $AB$ can be expressed in the form $U\Lambda V$ where $\sum_{i}U_{ij}^2 = 1, \sum_{j}V_{ij}^2 = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that any matrix product $AB$ can be expressed in the form $U\Lambda V$, where $U$ is
> a matrix in which the sum of the squares of the entries in each column is $1$, $V$ is a
> matrix in which the sum of the squares of the entries in each row is $1$, and $\Lambda$ is an
> appropriately chosen diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries on the diagonal.

So, we have that  $\sum_{i}u_{ij}^2 = 1, \sum_{j}V_{ij}^2 = 1$. $(AB)_{ij}= \sum_{r}a_{ir}b_{rj}$.
The i-th row of a $\Lambda V = (\lambda_iv_{i1},\lambda_iv_{i2},...,\lambda_iv_{id})$ and the $j$-th column is $(\lambda_1v_{1j},\lambda_2v_{2j},...,\lambda_nv_{nj})$. So, the $ij$-th entry of $(U\Lambda V)_{ij}  = (u_{i1},u_{i,2},...,u_{in})*(\lambda_1v_{1j},\lambda_2v_{2j},...,\lambda_nv_{nj})^t = \lambda_1v_{1j}u_{i1}+\lambda_2v_{2j}u_{i2}+...+\lambda_nv_{nj}u_{in} = \sum_{k}\lambda_k u_{ik}v_{kj}$. And we should show that $\sum_{r}a_{ir}b_{rj} = \sum_{k}\lambda_k u_{ik}v_{kj}$ for some $\lambda_k, u_{ik},v_{kj}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the matrices have real number entries. The result follows immediately from the singular value decomposition of $AB$.

Alternatively, let $AB$ be $m\times n$. Perform a rank decomposition $AB=XY$, so that $X$ is $m\times r$ and $Y$ is $r\times n$ with $r=\operatorname{rank}(X)=\operatorname{rank}(Y)=\operatorname{rank}(AB)$. Let $x_i$ be the Euclidean norm of the $i$-th column of $X$ and $y_i$ be the Euclidean norm of the $i$-th row of $Y$. Then $AB=U\Lambda V$ where
$$
U=X\operatorname{diag}(x_1,\ldots,x_r)^{-1},\ \Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(x_1y_1,\ldots,x_ry_r),\ V=\operatorname{diag}(y_1,\ldots,y_r)^{-1}Y.
$$
If you want $U$ and $V$ to be square matrices, just append some columns of unit norms to $U$, some rows of unit norms to $V$ and some zeroes to the diagonal of $\Lambda$.